PowerAutomate custom connector to IIS API always resolves to base url
Issue
I have a python flask API hosted on IIS using FastCGI. I created a custom connector in PowerAutomate using an on-premise gateway to call this API.  But no matter what actions are defined in the connector, it always resolves to the base URL.
Troubleshooting
I can get it working successfully in the following two tests:

Testing using the swagger editor in the connector (after enabling
CORs module in IIS)
Running the python flask app from command line instead of IIS

Simple Flask app with 3 routes for troubleshooting:

PowerAutomate Connector:

Connector Action:

Test Result going to base URL:

